# Getting 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type' error when doing a syncdb

Tags: django, heroku, geodjango

I'm attempting to run `heroku run python manage.py syncdb` on my GeoDjango app on Heroku, but I get the following error:

**AttributeError: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type'**

[All](http://djangosaur.tumblr.com/post/409277054/geodjango-database-engine-for-django-1-2) [of](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12727) [my](http://develissimo.com/forum/topic/110229/?page=1#post-267473) [research](http://opensourcegeospatial.blogspot.com/2011/06/geodjango-object-has-no-attribute.html) has yielded the same solution: make sure to use `django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis` as the database engine. Funny thing is that *I'm already doing this* (and I also have `django.contrib.gis` in `INSTALLED_APPS`):

```
settings.py

DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
    'NAME': '...',
    'HOST': '...',
    'PORT': ...,
    'USER': '...',
    'PASSWORD': '...'
  }
}

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...,
    'django.contrib.gis',
)
```

Is there something else I am missing? Any help is greatly appreciated, below is the full error trace for reference:

```
Running `python manage.py syncdb` attached to terminal... up, run.1
Creating tables ...
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site
Creating table django_admin_log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 91, in handle_noargs
    sql, references = connection.creation.sql_create_model(model, self.style, seen_models)
  File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 44, in sql_create_model
    col_type = f.db_type(connection=self.connection)
  File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 200, in db_type
    return connection.ops.geo_db_type(self)
AttributeError: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type'
```

**Update**: I followed the [GeoDjango tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/) and [Heroku/Django tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django), and built a simple app that works on my dev machine. I pushed it to Heroku using a [custom GeoDjango buildpack](https://github.com/cirlabs/heroku-buildpack-geodjango), and tried syncdb, but get the same error. Is this an issue with Django/GeoDjango, Heroku, or the buildpack? My dev environment is using PostgreSQL 9.1 and PostGIS 2.0, but Heroku uses 9.0.9 and 1.5, could that be the issue?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The buildpack was the primary culprit here. Instead of using the GeoDjango buildpack listed on [Heroku's buildpack page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/third-party-buildpacks), I used [one of it's forks](https://github.com/guybowden/heroku-buildpack-geodjango) that was updated more recently.

Also, when I do a `git push heroku master`, Heroku creates a dev database for the app, and when I do a syncdb, **my `DATABASES` setting is ignored** and Heroku tries to use the dev database
instead... obviously an issue, because dev databases don't/can't have PostGIS installed. So I destroyed the dev database after it was created with the `git push` (with the [correct buildpack](https://github.com/guybowden/heroku-buildpack-geodjango)), then ran syncdb and it works.

Comment: i am still getting this error after using the custom build pack.

Comment: While the question is Heroku specific, the title is quite general. The problem can also arise if Django DATABASES ENGINE is not set to django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis

Answer (score 100):

The OP was using the GeoDjango buildpack, but in case anyone gets here using [Geo buildpack](https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack/) and `dj_database_url` like I was, in `settings.py` don't forget the last line:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'
```

## UPDATE

`dj_database_url` [directly supports](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url#url-schema) PostGIS. You can do without the last line in the code above if you can change your database URL to start with `postgis`.

Comment: With setting issue can be fixed. While running the Django server it will cause an issue. Below @Sillson approach will solve the issue.  Issue Encounterd:: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/seenu/.venv/1729/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]`
KeyError: 'django'

Comment: Saved me, I guess, ton of time, because I'm not sure how would I find this reason. But strangely all seemed to work yesterday and I was surprised to see error today. IDK, maybe it was a dream. Thank you!

Comment: Now I am getting this error please help `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME value.`

Comment: for dokku, before linking use `dokku config:set POSTGRES_DATABASE_SCHEME=postgis`

Answer (score 41):

I got this error when trying to run tests with the test db set like so:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
            'NAME': '_testdb',
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the sqlite3 `DatabaseOperations` object doesn't have the attribute `geo_db_type` (like the title of this post suggests).

My solution was to change the backend to the sqlite equivalent GIS engine:

```
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.spatialite'
```

See the Django docs on GeoDjango installation for all the possible backends, with installation instructions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/#spatial-database

Comment: The link seems to be dead. Could you maybe post a new link AND copy the relevant text to your answer? Thank you!

Comment: Updated link.  Looks like v1.9 has been dead for awhile.

Answer (score 29):

I was having the same problem and I had to change:

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
```

to:

```
'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
```

Answer (score 18):

for me helped

1) add `'django.contrib.gis',` to `INSTALLED_APPS`
2) change from

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
```

to

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql',
```

Answer (score 13):

This post is old but I just wanted to share my answer to this problem. I'm using the Dj Database package, and I didn't know that the connection URL is different when using PostGIS. The connection string for PostGIS is `postgis://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/NAME`

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Actually this change on the URL save me the day!

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: what is connectoin string mean? where should i put it?

Answer (score 9):

I'm using the Python sample application on stack **cedar 14** and the regular Heroku buildpack **Heroku/python** with PostGIS and had the same problem that my database settings were overwritten with the wrong DB engine, which caused `heroku run python manage.py migrate` to fail with the above error.
Just adding the engine in the settings would not change anything.
After some investigation I found out that it is the call to `django_heroku.settings(locals())` in the last line of my settings.py which is reverting my changes.

I fixed it by overwriting the engine again like this by adding a line afterwards:

```
django_heroku.settings(locals())
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'
```

Comment: This totally fixed this for me.  I feel like this should be brought up as an issue with django_heroku, as I don't think this is intended functionality.

Comment: Excellent answer.  This fixed my problem.  For what it's worth `django_heroku` (and the newer `django_on_heroku`) now both accept a `geodjango=True` kwarg to avoid this probem [https://github.com/pkrefta/django-on-heroku#enabling-functionality]

Comment: Thank you so much. Now i also understood, what django_heroku really does.

Comment: thanks this solved my issue spent 4-5 hours trying to solve this

Answer (score 5):

I changed my default db engine from `psycopg2` to `postgis`

PREVIOUSLY

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        ...,
    }
}
```

NOW

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        ...,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Settings.py > INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
.
.
'django.contrib.gis'
.
]
```

> Settings.py > Databases

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql',
     ...,
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In may case I was having this issue because I forgot to comment out the db settings further down in settings.py:

```
# Update database configuration with $DATABASE_URL.
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

These lines were overriding the settings that I had added above. Adding this in case someone else had the same issue.