# django error: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type'

Tags: django, postgresql, gis

I have a django project that uses google maps. I wanted to create a GIS application using GeoDjango and Google Maps following [this](http://invisibleroads.com/tutorials/geodjango-googlemaps-build.html) tutorial but went through several issues.
Now I'm stuck, although I decided to remove everything but django still throwing this error regardless I removed all the details related to GIS:

```
AttributeError: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type'
```

I mean there is nothing at all that relate my django project (in the code) to GIS?!

I feel like installing GIS/postgres must have messed up the django default database system.

Any suggestions?

Comment: question is not clear , you should provide some illustrated error, or more detailed info

Comment: Thanks @KostiaMololkin, if you are familiar with django then there is no need to put too much details in my question. I was following that tutorial (see above) and once I added 'multiple databases' to my  'settings.py' I received the error in my question. Then I set 'settings.py' back to default but error still shooting out!!

Comment: I also deleted the 'db.sqlite3' and ran the migration again to get a new migration file, but no luck.

Comment: you can find solution here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46075739/geodjango-postgresql-not-running-migrations-object-has-no-attribute-geo-db-ty/46077599#46077599

Answer (score 1):

I think I will solve this problem by myself. I found two similar questions here in this place and no one solved them or gave a clear answer.
See this:

[GeoDjango error: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219414/geodjango-error-databaseoperations-object-has-no-attribute-geo-db-type)

Which means no clear solution and gotta get around it myself.
This post is thus closed.

Comment: I changed the default database that used by django and that solve my problem. I used the 'postgis'