# GeoDjango: PostgreSQL not running migrations, object has no attribute 'geo_db_type

Tags: python, django, postgresql, geodjango

Django v1.11.5

I'm trying to install GeoDjango to play around with GoogleMaps.

I installed PostgreSQL app for MAC and installed `pip install psycopg2`. I also used home-brew to install GDAL.

Edited **settings.py** to add:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'djangodb',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

However, when I run `python manage.py` migrate I get: `AttributeError: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type'`

I created the user using:`CREATE DATABASE djangodb OWNER admin;`

Full Error:

> Running migrations:   Applying users.0011_location...Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 22, in 
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 364, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 356, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 283, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 330, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py",
>   line 204, in handle
>       fake_initial=fake_initial,   File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py",
>   line 115, in migrate
>       state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
>   "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py",
>   line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
>       state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
>   "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py",
>   line 244, in apply_migration
>       state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)   File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py",
>   line 129, in apply
>       operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)   File
>   "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py",
>   line 97, in database_forwards
>       schema_editor.create_model(model)   File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py",
>   line 254, in create_model
>       definition, extra_params = self.column_sql(model, field)   File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py",
>   line 144, in column_sql
>       db_params = field.db_parameters(connection=self.connection)   File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py",
>   line 662, in db_parameters
>       type_string = self.db_type(connection)   File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py",
>   line 126, in db_type
>       return connection.ops.geo_db_type(self) AttributeError: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type'

Similar questions I tried:
[Getting 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type' error when doing a syncdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538510/getting-databaseoperations-object-has-no-attribute-geo-db-type-error-when-do)

Comment: You link to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538510/getting-databaseoperations-object-has-no-attribute-geo-db-type-error-when-do) but you have `django.db.backends.postgresql` instead of `django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis` in your `DATABASES` setting.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems to run migrations now. I've tried django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2 and the one listed in the question, all with errors. I even created new virtual env to test. Thanks again!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to change your `DATABASES` setting to use the postgis backend,

```
'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
```

and add `'django.contrib.gis'`, to `INSTALLED_APPS`.