# project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s) but migrations doesn't work

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run a panel on local. this error shows up when I run server:

> You have 149 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly >until you apply the migrations for app(s): account, admin, authtoken, >conf, easy_thumbnails, finance, messaging, order, payment, product, >sites, warehouse.
>   Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.````

I also tried this:

```
python3.6 manage.py makemigrations
```

it says:

> No changes detected

and finally when I use migrate command it says:

> AttributeError: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute >'geo_db_type'

Comment: are you using geodjango? and are you using postgres or mysql?

Comment: That isn't an error, it's a warning. You haven't asked a question.

Comment: you could be running in the sama issue like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21317596/2174832

Comment: @matyas postsql, no i don't

Comment: the problem is I can't run server @roganjosh

Comment: does this solution help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46077599/2174832

Comment: @matyas it's already been installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can happen when you try to save geo data on sqlite. 
try this out:

```
'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.spatialite'
```