# Error was: No module named sqlite3

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Settings for database are:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'dataBase',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': 'dataBase',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}
```

and exception generates :

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.sqlite3' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    u'mysql', u'oracle', u'postgresql_psycopg2', u'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named sqlite3.base
```

Following django documentations `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/`

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do GIS things - I'm not aware of any databases  besides Postgres that offer some GIS features.

Comment: Have you installed and configured [SpatiaLite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/gis/install/spatialite/)?

Answer (score 1):

change the conf. like this if you are using sqlite (by the this is just for reference made changes according to your need like dbname and etc.)

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
       'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'yourdbname.sqlite'), 
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',

  }
}
```

this will create db by name "yourdbname" where your apps settings.py resides plus you can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538510/getting-databaseoperations-object-has-no-attribute-geo-db-type-error-when-do) i guess it will help you

Comment: AttributeError: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type'

Comment: https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities/issues/6 go through it may be it can help you or else please provide some context

Answer (score 0):

If you use sqlite3 to store the data, you should change the conf file,here is an example , just change the db file location:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': './db.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': 'dataBase',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}
```

Comment: what should be the location of db?

Comment: The path of the db file, like "/hone/user/malik/django/db.db". Just an absolute path or the current path './db.db' is ok.

Comment: here is another exception `AttributeError: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type'
`