# Getting error with postgis Geodjango on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, postgis, geodjango

Postgis extension is installed:

```
 :DATABASE=> SELECT postgis_version();                                         
        postgis_version            

 2.2 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1
```

I have the following buildpacks:

1. https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack.git
2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git

When I run manage.py migrate I get:

```
AttributeError: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type'
```

I am using the hobby deb postgres which now supports postgis
https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/792

Do I need to install a different build pack or add some additional configuration? Everything works locally using postgis.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538510/getting-databaseoperations-object-has-no-attribute-geo-db-type-error-when-do?rq=1

Comment: I checked that post earlier and it didn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally had some time to go back and look at this. It turns out the issue was Heroku was not importing my settings correctly. I was using cookiecutter-django settings scheme that imports common settings into production and for some reason Heroku was not working as expected.

My common settings contained:

```
DATABASES['default']['ATOMIC_REQUESTS'] = True
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = "django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis"
```

And my production contained:

```
DATABASES['default'] = env.db("DATABASE_URL")
```

Heroku did not import those common settings. When I checked in the django shell in heroku the production settings had

```
 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False
```

After adding DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = "django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis" to production settings everything is working.

Does anybody know what could be going wrong with importing settings correctly from common.py? It seems to import the rest of the settings correctly, just not the database ones.