# Having hard time deploying Django + PostGis on AWS Beanstalk (DatabaseOperations error)

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, postgis

I’m having troubles making Django + PostGIS work on AWS BeanStalk.

The app runs, some parts of the app work properly,  but when trying to access object with GeoDjango fields (PointField) I get this error:

> Attribute Error
>
> 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'select'
>
> /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py
>   in select_format, line 61

I have googled this error, and very few people encountered it. The closest error I could find is: [Getting 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type' error when doing a syncdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538510/getting-databaseoperations-object-has-no-attribute-geo-db-type-error-when-do?rq=1)

But my databases is configured correctly in the Django Settings Module as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
       'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
       'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
       'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
       'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
       'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
   }
}
```

I’m using Django 1.9.5 with PostGis 2.3.0 and PostgreSQL 9.5.2

I’m using a custom AMI based on 2017.03 that I made using this script:

https://gist.github.com/nitrag/932ecd7d109f9d1e3ed378353e0d5c2f

PostGis is installing properly on the EC2 instance, I even tried another script and got the same final error. (http://www.daveoncode.com/2014/02/18/creating-custom-ami-with-postgis-and-its-dependencies-to-deploy-django-geodjango-amazon-elastic-beanstalk/)

I am really on my last legs here, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is rds security group properly configured ?

Comment: I did not do it, I think BeanStalk takes care of it. But anyway, If there was a security issue I could not create or retrieve any objects from RDS. In my case, some objects work (the ones without a GeoDjango field) and others produce the error I talk about in my question.