# AttributeError: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type' QGIS Docker container to Heroku

Tags: django, docker, heroku

There is a really old thread on stackoverflow here [Getting 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type' error when doing a syncdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538510/getting-databaseoperations-object-has-no-attribute-geo-db-type-error-when-do)

but the difference that I have with their issue is that my containers have the POSTGIS and POSTGRES installed in. Specifically I used QGIS and the image is like so

```
db:

image: kartoza/postgis:13.0

volumes:

- postgis-data:/var/lib/postgresql
```

So locally I have two docker images - one is web and the other is the kartoza/postgis

I also have this as well in the settings.py file

```
import dj_database_url

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)

DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

which should support the GIS data. I see all my packages gis, geolocation packages installed with no issues. But I am getting the above error when I run heroku run python manage.py migrate

The website runs with very limited functionality as the geo variables are needed to get you past the landing page.

The steps I have taken to deploy is

```
heroku create appname

heroku stack:set container -a appname

heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev -a appname

heroku git:remote -a appname

git push heroku main
```

**EDIT** The db url on heroku is `postgres://foobar:3242q34rq2rq32rf3q2rfq2q2r3vq23rvq23vr@er3-13-234-91-69.compute-`
I have also ran the below command and it shows that the db now takes GIS, but I still get the error

```
$ heroku pg:psql
create extension postgis;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after 14 or so hours of reading. The issue here is that

1. Heroku database does NOT have qgis capabilities enabled as a default - you have to use  `heroku pg:psql` then run `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`
2. Having QGIS installed within the docker container results it not being able to perform functions such as `hero pg:push localdatabase -postgresqlremoteherokudb` and `heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=postgis://foo:bar@localhost:5432/gis` So if anyone is following the python nearbyshops tutorial, you might end up here as well. I got fixated here thinking it's a db issue, but it was more so to do with heroku configuration settings.
3. If you are coming here from docker, which might mean you need to install django_heroku package to modify your settings. There are recent 2019 and 2018 guides on how to deploy Geospatial apps to heroku, but again, you don't need those. (at least for me I didn't)
4. GIS now is available as an extension, you no longer need to add buildpacks.

There are still some configuration issues if you are using gunicorn for staticfiles, so the website at first won't launch properly. Highly suggest that you track your heroku log errors (manual settings.py coding or heroku addons).

Answer (score 0):

try replacing db with localhost

```
heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=postgis://foo:bar@localhost:5432/gis
```

Comment: This isn't working. My docker container has both POSGIS and POSTGRES installed in it. Getting the same error. The DATABASE_URL is showing as //postgres1234567890wsfoobar when I insert the command ```heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev -a appname```. I think I have to figure out how to build a heroku database that has GIS capabilities.