# Why am I unable to set my GeoDjango database engine to 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis' on heroku?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, geodjango

I've had [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538510/getting-databaseoperations-object-has-no-attribute-geo-db-type-error-when-do) for several days now, and it seems like no matter what I do, I can't set my database engine to `'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'` on heroku. The problem has me so stuck that it's driven me to finally make my first Stack Overflow post.

I can see the engine is `'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'` when I check the database settings in heroku:

```
% heroku run bash
~ $ python manage.py shell
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.DATABASES
{'default': {'NAME': [name], 'USER': [user], 'PASSWORD': [password], 
'HOST': [host], 'PORT': 5432, 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 600, 'OPTIONS': {'sslmode': 'require'}, 
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 
'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'TIME_ZONE': None, 
'TEST': {'CHARSET': None, 'COLLATION': None, 'MIGRATE': True, 'MIRROR': None, 'NAME': None}}}
```

*I've come to believe that the problem has to do with me not understanding how heroku uses the django `settings.py` file to set up the database*. For example, I'm wondering if I'm doing things in the wrong order. Originally, I set up the heroku database with the below commands and then afterwards pushed my geodjango project to Heroku.

```
% heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
% heroku pg:psql
app::DATABASE=> create extension postgis;
```

I've also tried deleting the database entirely and then pushing my code to Heroku because I thought maybe heroku would automatically create the database after reading the `settings.py` file, but this didn't happen.

**More Information**:

I believe my heroku builpacks are set up correctly and don't think that's the problem:

```
1. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-geo-buildpack.git
2. heroku/python
```

The `DATABASES` variable in my `settings.py` file follows the recommendations of the many Stack Overflow threads already written on this problem, as shown below. I have pip installed dj_database_url and added it to my `requirements.txt`. I think I recall reading somewhere that django creates the database from the first mention of the `DATABASES` variable, so it won't read the last line where I re-set the engine to `'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'`. Maybe that's the problem?

```
DATABASES = {}

import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'
```

My most immediate question is: how do I set the database engine in heroku `'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'`? I also want to understand how the heroku uses the django settings.py file to set up the app?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you call `django_heroku.settings(locals())` somewhere in your settings file? After this database config?

Comment: Yes, I do. It's located at the bottom of my settings file, below the DATABASES variable.

Comment: `django_heroku.settings` is overwriting your db settings, try setting `DATABASES['default']['ENGINE']` after this call? Or there must be a way to configure `django_heroku` to use a different engine somehow

Comment: Wow that was correct, holy cow. Never would have guessed. Thanks so much @IainShelvington!